# Question concerning dealloc and applicationWillTerminate

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have literally the same problem, as described here
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/968-breakpoints-dealloc.html#post7406

Sorry for the quote, but the description is perfect.

Because my dealloc is also not called automatically, my question is, am I supposed to overwrite applicationWillFinish and call [self release] in order to not leave any leak?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to worry about 'cleaning up' memory when your app quits; the OS will nuke your address space from orbit (it's the only way to be sure). If you have non-memory-related cleanup to do (perhaps save temp info to a file), that should go in applicationWillTerminate:. No need to call [self release].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe iPhone OS just doesn't bother with calling dealloc because your app is going to terminate anyway? Any cleanup code should go in `applicationWillTerminate`, and *you don't* need to call `[self release];`.

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure about this? The "iPhone 3 development book" is very emphatic on right dealloc behavior. They are doing every kind of cleanup in "dealloc".